# Using a string that starts with a number to display a substring of that many characters

Tags: java

I'm trying to wrap my head around this problem and any help would be appreciated. I am trying to get the user to enter a string, beginning with a single digit (1-9). When the string is entered I need to print a substring, but only up to the number that was entered. For example, if the user was to type "4 big houses", my output should be "4 bi". I have it displaying correctly, however my code is very long winded with a lot of else if statements.

What would an alternative method be to reduce the amount of line of code?

Also, as is, I get a "string index out of range" exception if the user does not enter enough characters, ie if the string starts with a 4, but only contains 3 characters...

```
         else if (text.substring(0,1).matches("[0-9]"))         
          { 

            if (text.substring(0,1).matches("1"))               
            { 

                String text2 = text.substring(0, 1);
                System.out.println("The decoded string is: " + text2 + ", and starts with a 1!");
            }
            else if (text.substring(0,1).matches("2"))
            { 
                String text2 = text.substring(0, 2);
                System.out.println("The decoded string is: " + text2 + ", and starts with a 2!");
            }
            else if (text.substring(0,1).matches("3"))
            { 
                String text2 = text.substring(0, 3);
                System.out.println("The decoded string is: " + text2 + ", and starts with a 3!");
            }
            else if (text.substring(0,1).matches("4"))
            { 
                String text2 = text.substring(0, 4);
                System.out.println("The decoded string is: " + text2 + ", and starts with a 4!");
            }
            else if (text.substring(0,1).matches("5"))
            { 
                String text2 = text.substring(0, 5);
                System.out.println("The decoded string is: " + text2 + ", and starts with a 5!");
            }
            else if (text.substring(0,1).matches("6"))
            { 
                String text2 = text.substring(0, 6);
                System.out.println("The decoded string is: " + text2 + ", and starts with a 6!");
            }
            else if (text.substring(0,1).matches("7"))
            { 
                String text2 = text.substring(0, 7);
                System.out.println("The decoded string is: " + text2 + ", and starts with a 7!");
            }
            else if (text.substring(0,1).matches("8"))
            { 
                String text2 = text.substring(0, 8);
                System.out.println("The decoded string is: " + text2 + ", and starts with a 8!");
            }
            else if (text.substring(0,1).matches("9"))
            { 
                String text2 = text.substring(0, 9);
                System.out.println("The decoded string is: " + text2 + ", and starts with a 9!");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well if the first character should be a number between 1 and 9, shouldn't you use `[1-9]` instead of `[0-9]`? The latter would allow the number `0`, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the first character of your string to an int, and then collapse all your variants for 1 - 9 into one using that int value. To prevent the "string index out of bounds" message, just check the string is long enough:

```
if (text.substring(0,1).matches("[0-9]")) {
  int charCount = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(0, 1));
  String text2 = text;
  if (text.length() > charCount) {
    text2 = text.substring(0, charCount);
  }
  System.out.println(text2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to grab the first character in the string and convert it to a number.

So:

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(0,1));
String text2 = text.substring(0,number);
System.out.println("The decoded string is: " + text2 + ", and starts with a " + number +"!");
```

`parseInt()` can throw a `NumberFormatException` if the first character isn't a number, so maybe use a `try/catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

don't use if/else for this. Store the number entered in a variable and use it in the substring() method

NOTE: not totally correct syntax-example ONLY

```
if(text[0].matches([0-9]){
    var endPoint= parseInt(text[0]);//parseInt means parseInteger
    String text2 = text.substring(0, endPoint);
    System.out.println("The decoded string is: " + text2 + ", and starts with a"+endPoint+"!");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String sub = text.substring(0,1);

if(sub.matches("[0-9]")) {
    try{
    System.out.println("The decoded string is: "
        + text.substring(0, Integer.parseInt(sub))
        + "and starts with a " + sub + "!");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

The try-catch is in case your String is too short.

Answer (score 0):

A "hack" sort of an example, if you need a really short version :-)

```
int len = text.charAt(0)-0x30;
if( len > 0 && len < 10 ) { 
    System.out.printf("The decoded string is: %s, and starts with a %d!\n", 
        s.substring(0, len), len);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String sourceText = "4 test";

    // Validate input first
    if (sourceText == null || sourceText.isEmpty() || !Character.isDigit(sourceText.charAt(0))) {
        System.out.println("The string must start with a digit.");
        return;
    }
    // Use getNumericValue instead of Integer.parseInt
    int count = Character.getNumericValue(sourceText.charAt(0));
    String resultText = count < sourceText.length() ? sourceText.substring(0, count) : sourceText;

    // Use String.format
    System.out.println(String.format("The decoded string is \"%s\" and starts with a %d!", resultText, count));
```